# Config file for c# windows service

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I have this configuration file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="AuxAppStg0" value="5 iunie 2013 19:22:49" />
        <add key="AuxAppStg1" value="5 iunie 2013 00:00:00" />
        <add key="AppStg2" value="5 iunie 2013 19:23:04" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And I want to parse it using this code:

```
 // Get the configuration file.
        System.Configuration.Configuration config =
            ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        // Get the appSettings section.
        System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection appSettings =
            (System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection("appSettings");



        foreach (KeyValueConfigurationElement i in appSettings.Settings)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: {1}", i.Key, i.Value);
        }

        if (appSettings.Settings.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (string key in appSettings.Settings.AllKeys)
            {
                string value = appSettings.Settings[key].Value;
                Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: {1}", key, value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The appSettings section is empty. Write first.");
        }
```

and all I get is : *The appSettings section is empty. Write first.*
I have found it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.appsettingssection.aspx). What I am doing wrong? I want to make a config file for a c# windows service to read at startup, is this a good approach, any other better aproaches?

Comment: What is the name of your .config file? It should be the name of the service executable + .config at the end, so `MyWindowsService.exe` should be `MyWindowsService.exe.config`. It should also be in the same directory as your service executable. You also need to restart your windows service for it to pick up changes to the file.

Comment: Why aren't you using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings?

Comment: @matt-dot-net Good catch, +1 for that.

Comment: you know how they say..  @matt-dot-net: true story!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you have to import `System.configuration` reference into your project.

Then you can use something like this:

```
private void ParseAppSettings() {
    string value = string.Empty;
    foreach (string key in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys)
    {
        value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
        Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: {1}", key, value);
    } 
}
```